# Update JIRA Customfield value using java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm simply trying to update a customfield value in jira using java. I had created a method `updateCustomField` which accepts 3 parameters (`customFieldCode`, `value`, `jiraId`). Had tried using transition but all it did is change the jira status from "Open" to "Resolved 2". I googled everywhere but they suggest to use JSON which I have no idea how to apply.

here's my update method:

```
public void updateCustomField(String customFieldCode, String value, String jiraId) throws Exception {
    final IssueRestClient issueRestClient = jiraClient.getIssueClient();
    final Issue issue = issueRestClient.getIssue(jiraId).get();
    FieldInput fieldInput = new FieldInput(customFieldCode, value);
    List <FieldInput> fields = new ArrayList <FieldInput> ();
    fields.add(fieldInput);
    TransitionInput transision = new TransitionInput(1, fields);
    issueRestClient.transition(issue, transision);

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who want to simply update jira using java, you can try this [jira-client](https://github.com/rcarz/jira-client/tree/master/src/main/java/net/rcarz/jiraclient) library.